# INSERT QUERY doesn't work can't fix it

Tags: python, mysql

This code doesn't work and I can't fix it. I need help.

```
Firstname = input("Firstname: ")
Lastname = input("Lastname: ")
Form = input("Form: ")
Phone = input("Phone: ")
Address = input("Address: ")
date= input("Date of birth: ")
gender = input("Gender: ")
email = input("Email: ")
c.execute("INSERT INTO Students(Firstname,Lastname,Form,Phone,Address,Date_of_birth,Gender,email) VALUES('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')".format(Firstname,Lastname,Form,Phone,Address,date,gender,email))
print(Firstname,Lastname,"Has been added to the database")
```

Comment: what do you mean it "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? Are the changes not being made? Be more specific.

Comment: what means   {} ?????

Comment: The code doesn't do anything it doesn't show any errors but doesn't do the changes. the {} are for the values. I have another code working but this one doesn't.

Comment: My first guess would be about the Date. Is it a datetime field? Are you typing it in a proper way, like 'yyyy-MM-dd'? Does the table have any id/primary key? Is it set to autoincrement? Since you ommited it in the query.

Comment: Could you post your table schema?

Comment: date are strings

Comment: I fixed it I just forgot to put con.commit()